# C++ OpenMP parallel slower than serial

Tags: c++, optimization, graph, parallel-processing, openmp

I have implemented a parallel code in C++ for finding minimum spanning tree with Prim's algorithm using OPENMP. Sometimes it is a little bit faster (7.95 msec) but sometimes I get a speed up of 12.7 msec which is much slower that the serial version (for which i get 9.69 msec)
Here there is the parallel version of my code:

https://dpaste.de/dUt6

Can you please help out with this?

Moreover, is there a valid method for testing the performance of my code? time.h seems not to be precise.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Briefly looking at your code I would suggest trying a larger value of V (you have it set to 1000). OpenMP has an overhead so you won't see its benfit before some threshold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenMP has an overhead which adds a constant term to the time calculation.  Let me give an example.

Let's assume your algorithm finishes in `A*n` where A is some constant and n is the number of items you will iterate over.  Let's also assume that your algorithm parallelizes perfectly so that if you have `k` threads the parallelized algorithm finishes in `O(n)/k` time.  Due to the OpenMP overhead the time to run will be `A*n/k + B` where B is the overhead.  Therefore, in order for you to see any benfit from OpenMP `A*n/k + B < A*n`.  For some range of values of n [0, threshhold] OpenMP will actually be slower than the serial algoirhtm due to the overhead `B`.

Another important point is that OpenMP has a different overhead/threshold depending on if it has already been used in the code.  I call this the cold and warm thresholds.

```
dtime_cold = omp_get_wtime();
foo();  //cold  - OpenMP has not been called before
dtime_cold = omp_get_wtime() - dtime_cold;

dtime_warm = omp_get_wtime();
foo(); //warm - OpenMP has already been called once
dtime_warm = omp_get_wtime() - dtime_warm;
```

If `n` is large enough then the constant terms are insignficant in which case the thresholds don't matter.